# Nueva Base de Datos de Firestore - ¿Cómo hago una copia de seguridad?

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-firestore

¿Como puedo crear otro servicio de base de datos de Google Firestore en el mismo proyecto de Firebase o GCP?
La idea es tener una base de datos de Firestore como copia de seguridad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diferencia de realtimedatabase no podes hacer una copia de seguridad guardando la base de datos como soliamos hacer.

Para firestore vas a tener que correr una cloud function que te obtenga todos los datos de tu base de datos, podes sincronizar esta funcion para que se ejecute en determinados tiempos

Exportar data: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import

Programar el exportado: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/schedule-export